# How to configure Jaeger collector with ElasticSearch in Windows Server

Tags: elasticsearch, opentracing, jaeger

I am trying to setup jaeger-collector on one server with jaeger-agent running in another server.
If I run the exe jaeger-all-in-one, everything works as expected (using in memory).
In order to see the options available with ES, i am not able to run a help command. When I run jaeger-collector --help, it shows only cassandra related flags. How do I check the elastic search specific details.
Now, my requirement is to specify and elastic search url.
I have set up the Environment variables SPAN_STORAGE_TYPES and ES_SERVER_URLS, but couldn't find how to run jaeger-collector.exe by asking it to take in these environment variables.

Thanks,
Minu

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also interested.

Comment: Yes, I was able to set the environment variables: SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE = elasticsearch, ES_USERNAME = username, ES_PASSWORD = password, ES_SERVER_URLS = 'elasticsearch_url'. With these environment variables set, if collector is run, it picks up the values on its own.